# OS .CWD Skips One DIR how to fix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get directory from where  script is ran, but os.cwd() skips one dir

Script Path - D:\Mainfolder\Testfolder\testfoldr2\check1.py

But

Output is  - D:\Mainfolder\Testfolder

Why no testfolder2 is coming though the script is stored there kindly suggest how to get testfolder2 as working dir

I am Using for checking

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

`getcwd()` will give you your working directory from where you are running the script,

if you want folder of the file then you can use below code:

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print(path)
```